# How can I avoid using a dash in “which is a better source-“?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

The original sentence:

> Which is a better source of news—newspaper or TV?

I changed it to:

> Which is a better source of news between newspaper and TV?

Is that correct? Anyway, I want to change it into a complete sentence without dash. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is grammatically correct, although I personally think it sounds slightly awkward.

As mentioned in the comments, you could replace the dash with a colon or comma:

> Which is a better source of news: newspaper or TV?
>
> Which is a better source of news, newspaper or TV?

---

You could also invert the sentence in one of the following ways.

> Between newspaper and TV, which is a better source of news?
>
> Of newspaper and TV, which is a better source of news?
>
> Is newspaper or TV a better source of news?

Comment: I think you have given all the best options here.